# Determination of velocity and acceleration from s-t graph

Tags: graphing-functions

Suppose , a particle is moving away with constant acceleration . It passes distance s by time t . A chart of their values is given in the following :

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
t & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 8 & 10\\
\hline
s & 0 & 10 & 42 & 120 & 192 & 280\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

I have drawn a graph of t in x-axis and s in y-axis .The graph is as follows :
[image]

I want to determine the initial velocity and acceleration from this graph . I know that initial velocity is the velocity at time t = 0 . And we can get velocity from the slope of s-t graph . But I can't determine initial velocity and acceleration .

Comment: Do you know the 3 equations of uniform motion - especially the one connecting $s$ and $a$ and $t$?

Comment: yes . I know  the 3 equations of uniform motion - especially the one connecting s and a and t . That equation is s = ut + 0.5 * a*t*t .

Comment: Then you can use what njguliyev posted - exactly what I was about to tell.

Comment: I cant use the formula rather I have to determine intial velocity and acceleration from graph . Can you plz see the question carefully ?

Comment: I could not find a matching sequence in the oeis: http://oeis.org/search?q=10+42+120+192+280&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Wait, this one it is: http://oeis.org/A067728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find $v$ and $a$ using your table if $s = vt+a\frac{t^2}{2}$.

Comment: I cant use the formula rather I have to determine intial velocity and acceleration from graph . Can you plz see the question carefully ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "from graph", but I can explain how to find $v$ and $a$ more "high-school-like", i.e. without using the abovementioned formula. Since your particle is moving with constant acceleration the velocity increases the same amount (which equals the acceleration) during every second. So the mean velocity between times $6$ and $8$ will be equal to the velocity at $t=7$: $v(7)=36$. By the same reasoning we have $v(9)=44$. Therefore $a=\frac{44-36}{2}=4$. Now you know the acceleration and the velocity at time $7$, so the initial velocity $v(0)=36-4 \cdot 7 = 8$.

Comment: Many many thanks for your valuable lecture .This comment is very useful for me to get solution of this problem .

Comment: Well . I want to know another question . How can you tell that at t= 7 , the value of v(7) is 36 ?

Comment: $v(7)$ is equal to the mean velocity between times $6$ and $8$:
$$\frac{192-120}{2}.$$